# Show $ n + \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq (n + a \mathbb{Z}) \cap (n + b \mathbb{Z}) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-set-theory

let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I want to show

$$ n + \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq (n + a \mathbb{Z}) \cap (n + b \mathbb{Z}) $$

for integers $a,b$

TRY:

Since $lcm(a,b)$ is multiple of $a,b$, then $lcm(a,b) = ka = k'b$. Therefore $n + lcm(a,b) = n + ka \mathbb{Z} = n + bk' \mathbb{Z} $. and hence $ n + \operatorname{lcm}(a,b)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq (n + a \mathbb{Z}) \cap (n + b \mathbb{Z}) $

Comment: $lcm(a,b)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq a \mathbb{Z}$, hence $n + lcm(a,b)\mathbb{Z} \subseteq (n + a \mathbb{Z})$

Comment: why the downvote ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Show that if $r$ is a multiple of $s$, then $n+r\Bbb Z\subseteq n+s\Bbb Z$.

Comment: i have updated my qs with my try. Does it look  better now?

Comment: @DonAnselmo: Yes, though you might add something like ‘since clearly $ak\Bbb Z\subseteq a\Bbb Z$’.

Comment: thank you very much Brian. You are always very helpful.

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Note that $\def\lcm{\mathop{\rm lcm}}\lcm(a,b)$ is a multiple of $a$ and $b$, that is, there are $k_a$, $k_b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $\lcm(a,b) = k_aa = k_bb$.

Comment: i have updated my qs with my try. Does it look  better now?